# Is there an isotope effect for diffusion of an ion through a crystal lattice?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Consider the diffusion of natural abundance $\ce{Li^{+}}$ and $\ce{{}^{6}Li^{+}}$ through a crystalline matrix, say a spinel such as $\ce{LiMn2O4}$.  The two lithium ions will have the same ionic radius and electric charge.  They will differ only in atomic weight.  Is there any reason to believe that the lighter isotope, $\ce{{}^{6}Li^{+}}$, will diffuse through the crystal any faster than the natural abundance isotope?  When I consider the forces acting upon the ions in the crystal, I come up with coloumbic, dispersion and hard shell repulsive forces.  I cannot see how any of those would change by simply changing the mass of the ion.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Consider diffusion to be an attempt frequency times a probability of making the jump over the barrier.  The barrier likely doesn't change (as you note the forces do not). But the attempt frequency will since the mass of the atom rattling around in a potential minimum does vary.  Also, given you can separate isotopes through liquid or gas diffusion, what is special about solid diffusion to prevent it from happening?

Comment: This makes sense. I agree that there should be nothing special about isotope separation in a solid matrix versus liquid or gas...except maybe the magnitude of the separation. Perhaps what I really wanted to ask but didn't realize at the time is how one might go about quantifying the difference in diffusion rates for the two isotopes on a theoretical basis. Probably a very difficult problem though

Comment: Focus on the attempt frequency: the atom is to first order a simple harmonic oscillator in the potential well - so it will vary as 1/sqrt(mass)...

Comment: One paper to get you started might be N.L. Peterson et al., J. Phys C, Vol 6, 2020-2039 (1973) on "Isotope effect for silver diffusion in AgBr and AgCl"

Answer (score 1):

$F = ma$, so a less massive isotope should move faster, depending on the forces moving it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was wondering if a situation similar to a terminal drift velocity would be setup in a crystal in the same way it happens in a liquid.

Comment: Or, is there any reason to believe that any of the forces acting on the ion might decrease when lithium-6 is involved?